# Intellij intention 'Creates missing switch branches' not working

Tags: intellij-idea

Intellij's 'Creates missing switch branches' intention seems not to be working for me. I have enabled/disabled/enabled it with restarts of intellij, but I never get the alt-enter possibility to create a completed switch statement.

Am I missing something? I'm working with the latest version of intellij ultimate.

[image: enabled-intention]

Comment: Can you give an example code snippet where you would like to use the inspection?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that works :

```java
class SwitchBranches {
    public static final int ONE = 1;
    public static final int TWO = 2;
    public static final int THREE = 3;
    void x(@MagicConstant(intValues = {ONE, TWO, THREE}) int i) {
        switch (i) { // position the text caret on the `i` expression or on the switch keyword

        }
    }
}
```

If you need this functionality to create a switch statement for enum values, use the `Enum 'switch' statement that misses case` inspection. It is enabled by default at the "No highlighting, only fix" level. Example:

```java
enum EnumExample {
  A, B, C;

  void x(EnumExample e) {
    switch (e) {
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh, i didn't know that required the magic constant annotation. I copy pasted your example and it worked. Not sure though how it works with string enums?

Basically I thought Intellij could automatically generate switch statements for all enum values. That would help me code much quicker.